# How to create multiple select element based on the numbers in javascript or reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, user-interface, frontend

**I am working on a dummy project. I have to select a option and those options mapped with a numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6....). if I select number 3 option it will automatically create 3 input elements.**

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We cannot write your code for you, please give us what you've tried so far and we can try to help you find out why it's not working. We can't just write whole files of code for you, though. That's not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to add more details in the future, here is an example in Javascript

```
<div id="options-container"></div>

<script>
  function createInputElements(num) {
    const optionsContainer = document.getElementById("options-container");
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      const input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.setAttribute("placeholder", `Input ${i + 1}`);
      optionsContainer.appendChild(input);
    }
  }

  const option = 3;
  createInputElements(option);
</script>
```

For the example I wrote out when you select the number 3 option, it will call the createInputElements function and pass 3 as an argument. The function will then create 3 input elements and add them to the options container div. You can adjust the logic and styles according to your requirements.